# How to get the author from the "channelDelete" event Discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to create an anti-crash function, but got confused at the moment that the channel does not return the author. How can I get the author in another way?
I tried to connect to AuditLogEvent, but it didn't work
My code:

```
const { AuditLogEvent } = requier('discord.js')

const usersMap = new Map();

const LIMIT = 3;

const TIMES = 10000

bot.rest.on('channelDelete', async channel => {
  const fetchedLogs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type:  AuditLogEvent.ChannelDelete,
    })
  const deletionLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
  const { executor, target } = deletionLog

  if(channel.guild.id != "940990129307263046") return
    
    if(usersMap.has(executor.id)) {
      const userData = usersMap.get(executor.id);
      const { lastDelete, timer } = userData;
      let deleteCount = userData.deleteCount;
      const tim = channel.createdTimestamp - lastDelete.createdTimestamp
      if(tim > TIMES) {
        usersMap.delete(executor.id)
      } else {
        ++deleteCount;
        if(parseInt(deleteCount) === LIMIT) {
          executor.ban()
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Try logging `deletionLog` to the console before you extract `executor` and `target` from it

Comment: It returns user and channel information

Comment: Then, if `deletionLog` returns the user information, shouldn't you have everything you need?